# Spring Batch Transaction Exception:Existing transaction detected in JobRepository

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-batch

I am trying this and get exception:
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Existing transaction detected in JobRepository. Please fix this and try again (e.g. remove @Transactional annotations from client).

Is there anyone who have encountered this problem?

```
   @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void method1() // this method must be Transactional 
{

    ...    /*code to call JMS services*/

  method2();
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public void method2()
{
  batchService.runJobWithId(123L);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue like this:

- Create a new bean exclusively to launch the batch job.
- Add @Transaction(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED) on that bean.
- Configure a task executor for spring batch. something like:

spring-batch.xml:

```
<beans:bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <beans:property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    <beans:property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor" />
</beans:bean>
```

Application-context.xml

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="10" />
    <property name="keepAliveSeconds" value="120" />
</bean>
```

What does the trick is the task executor. If you check your logs spring batch will complain that, since no task executor is defined, it reverts to synchronous task execution, which is on the same thread. Using the configuration above jobs will be launched on a different thread.

**Important note**
Altough I managed for a while without configuring a taskExecutor, I ran into the twilight zone when I added a JobListener to update my own tables with start and end times for the job. Any DB Updates the jobListener performed would be reverted when the StartJob() call returned. So, I recommend that you execute your jobs in a separated thread. Simpler. Cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)` from `method2()`

Comment: unfortunately it did not work. Throwed same exception

Comment: SB has its own transaction management so avoid @Transactional annotation. Have you tried removing ALL transactional annotations?

Comment: When i am removing all @Transactional annotations, it works. But i am needing this @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED),  on 'method1' for same processes. Are there any alternative for  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)?

Comment: call `batchService.runJobWithId(123L)` from `method1()`

Comment: This is the correct answer.  In short, using `@Transactional` is a no-no from within Spring Batch jobs because of the transaction management that the framework itself provides.