# Integration of Spring Batch leads to TransactionRequiredException in previously functioning @Transactional Methods

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-batch, entitymanager

**Summary**

After adding a Spring Batch configuration to a Spring Boot application, execution of existing methods marked as @Transactional no longer works. A TransactionRequiredException  is thrown.

**Environment & Settings**

Maven hierarchy + dependencies:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
```

Our configuration mainly uses default settings, which are defined by annotations:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class BasicBeansConfig {
    @Autowired
    EntityManager em;
    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper om;

}
```

Our datasource is defined via a .properties file

```
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/localDatabase
spring.datasource.username=...
spring.datasource.password=...
```

With this configuration, it was possible to mark methods with @Transactional annotation and use EntityManager there (e.g. in a @Service).

**Problem**

The integration of Spring Batch (version managed via spring-boot-starter-parent) with the following configuration leads to javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException in these  @Transactional methods.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer() {

        return new DefaultBatchConfigurer() {

            @Override
            protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
                JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
                factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
                factory.setTransactionManager(getTransactionManager());
                factory.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE");
                factory.setTablePrefix("BATCH_");
                factory.setMaxVarCharLength(1000);
                return factory.getObject();
            }

        };
    }
}
```

After searching the web i have tried to extend the DefaultBatchConfigurer overriding the getTransactionManager() method and providing a JPATransactionManager using the autowired EntityManagerFactory:

```
            @Override
            public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {

                return new JpaTransactionManager(emFactory);
            }
```

But that did not solve the problem. How can I configure Spring Batch so that transaction management works correctly for both Spring Batch and other functions in the same Spring Boot application?

Comment: `execution of existing methods marked as @Transactional no longer works`: Do these methods no longer work when used inside the batch job or somewhere else in the app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Batch Transaction Exception:Existing transaction detected in JobRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26862521/spring-batch-transaction-exceptionexisting-transaction-detected-in-jobrepositor)

Comment: It's working now. Unfortunately, I don't know exactly why. Spring configuration pain :/ My posted attempt at a solution was already the right way. Thank you for your efforts!

(It was about methods somewhere else in the app)